# invoking keyboard shortcut from Windows 8 desktop using perl script

Tags: perl

I want to write a Perl script which should send the following keys from the desktop in following sequence.

1. <kbd>ctr</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>
2. <kbd>enter</kbd>
3. <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>
4. <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
5. <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Anybody knows how to do it from the Perl script?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into AutoIt? You will find tons of information on how to do stuff like that in the AutoIt community.

Then, go back to perl and look for a `SendKeys` API in the windows stuff. It's been 15 years since I last had ActivePerl installed, but if I remember correctly, there was a bunch of windows libraries there you could use.

If you don't have libraries like that, then you will need to figure out how to tap into the windows API directly. This should not be too difficult. Look for `SendKeys` API. And you might want to find the `hwnd` of the Desktop.

(There. A bunch of pointers, sorry about not having a solution, but these hints will get you there!)

So I found this module: [Win32::GuiTest](http://search.cpan.org/~erngui/Win32-GuiTest-1.3/GuiTest.pm) and it seems it could be as easy as this:

```
Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("^{ESCAPE");
Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("{ENTER}");
Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("{LWIN}<-");
Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("{LWIN}D");
Win32::GuiTest::SendKeys("{LWIN}E");
```

Comment: thank you Daren..One more question like sendkeys i have to select the windows first for which i want to use these keyboard shortcuts ,But i have to do these from win8 desktop itself how would i go about it...

Comment: `Win32:GUI:GetDesktopWindow()`?